# Python-docx Copy Table

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have the following code which I am using to save a table, modify the table, and then make a copy of the table. I got `copy_table_after()` from [Here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/156).

```
def copy_table_after(table, paragraph):
    tbl, p = table._tbl, paragraph._p
    new_tbl = deepcopy(tbl)
    p.addnext(new_tbl)

def replaceText(document, search, replace):
    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for paragraph in row.cells:
                if search in paragraph.text:
                    paragraph.text = replace

document = Document('Test.docx')
template = document.tables[0]
replaceText(document, '<<VALUE_TO_FIND>>', 'New value')
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
copy_table_after(template, paragraph)
```

My problem is that when I run `copy_table_after`, it copies the table with the new text. Is there a way to 'save' the table and then make a copy of the original table after I have already made changes to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible like this :

(Note that I have removed copy_table_after, because we just want to copy the table)

```
def replaceText(document, search, replace):
    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for paragraph in row.cells:
                if search in paragraph.text:
                    paragraph.text = replace

document = Document('Test.docx')
template = document.tables[0]
tbl = template._tbl
 # Here we do the copy of the table
new_tbl = deepcopy(tbl)
# Then we do the replacement
replaceText(document, '<<VALUE_TO_FIND>>', 'New value')
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
# After that, we add the previously copied table
paragraph._p.addnext(new_tbl)
```

Comment: How would I copy the table multiple times? I tried rerunning `paragraph._p.addnext(new_tbl)` but it doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: I am not sure how to do it without saving the file, and then reopening it and copying it once again

Comment: @Bijan I was having this problem too, but I realized that there was a bug in my code. It's important that you follow the order as shown above: (1) save the table in a temporary variable, (2) make the text replacements (3) append the table. Otherwise, you're going to overwrite the replacement targets in your template one time and then copy that forward forever, because your template will have been lost.